# Changes do not affevt on the map function and do not show :)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a chat app basically i'm calling a function that get the message and push it to an array of objects the array looks like this

```
newChat = [{message: "new message ", className: "you", date: new Date()}]
```

and the code looks like this

```
const send_message = (message) => {
    newChat.push({
        message: message,
        className: 'you',
        date: new Date().toString()
    })
    console.log(newChat)
}
const [message, setmessage] = useState(null)

return (
    <div className="chat">
        {
            newChat.map((message, index) => (
                <div className={message.className} key={index}>
                    <div className="message-container">
                        <h1 className={`message-${message.className}`}>{message.message}</h1>
                        <h5 className="date">{message.date.split('T')[0] + ' ' + message.date.split('T')[1]}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))
        }
        <div className="input-container">
            <Input onChange={(e) => setmessage(e.target.value)} placeholder="Write a message" />
            <Button onClick={() => send_message(message)} type="primary">Send</Button>
        </div>

        
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Chat

the problem is that the message get pushed to the array but do not show on the screen any suggestions please :) [image]

Comment: `newChat` needs to be part of some React state in order to be updated and trigger a rerender. Once you move it into React state you will want to also update it using immutable patterns, i.e. don't mutate the array by pushing values into it.

Answer (score 1):

React re-render when state or props has changed. To update component whenever newchat changes, you need to declare it as a state.

```
const [newChat, setNewChat] = useState([{message: "new message ", className: "you", date: new Date()}])

const send_message = (message) => {
    setNewChat([
       ...newChat,
       {
          message: message,
          className: 'you',
          date: new Date().toString()
       }
    ]);
}
```